# Not able to talk to WebApi from Actual device though app works fine in Ripple

Tags: cordova, azure, asp.net-web-api, ripple

I have developed an app in Cordova and have the backend being served by.Net API hosted on Azure. When I try to run the app using Ripple, I can talk to the API using the remote settings.

However if I try to install the same on actual device and run the app, I get

`error 404 Resource not found`

Answer (score 1):

Check the Android Manifest.xml if internet access allowed.

```
<manifest xlmns:android>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
</manifest>
```

Sometimes Cordova don't add this to the xml.

You can find the Manifest-file in your project folder under `/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks mkey, I am working with VS 2015 and was not able to find AndroidManifest.xml. though I added config-file node in config.xml and still this is not working

Comment: I added the key in Android Manifest file however I am still getting 404 error.